# Concat operation in property mediator of wso2 is invalid

Tags: wso2

```
 <property name="Code" expression="json-eval($.Code)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <property name="Endpoint" expression="json-eval($.data.InternalConfig.Events.Code.Endpoint)" scope="default" 


 <property expression="fn:concat(json-eval($.data.InternalConfig.Events'.'get-property('Code')'.'Endpoint)" name="URL" type="STRING" scope="default"/>
```

one property is fetching from payload and another from respository , i am trying to merge into 1 property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are trying to extract the data from the payload using dynamic values during the runtime. If yes, we can make use of [Script Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Script+Mediator) in the WSO2 platform to access the JSON payloads.

For example:

Given below is a sample payload, and you are trying to extract the data: `'some value here'` from the payload using the `code` and `endpoint` values

```json
{
    "userId": 10,
    "code": 1,
    "body": {
        "id": 2,
        "endpoint": "some-key",
        "1": {
            "anotherId": 30,
            "title": "Lorum ipsum",
            "some-key": "some value here"
        }
    }
}
```

Given below is a sample mediation sequence with the Script mediator to achieve your requirement

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="mediation-sequence">

    <script language="js">
        <![CDATA[

            // read the JSON payload from the message context
            var payload = mc.getPayloadJSON();

            // read the property values
            var code = payload["code"];
            var endpoint = payload["body"]["endpoint"];

            var extracted_value = payload["body"][code][endpoint];

            // set the extracted value as property to message context
            mc.setProperty("ExtractedValue", extracted_value);
        ]]>
    </script>

    <log level="custom">
        <property name="Extracted value" expression="$ctx:ExtractedValue" />
    </log>
</sequence>
```

Hope this helps you to achieve your requirement.